# Setup was unable to validate logged in user

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server

I'm trying to upgrade SQL Server 2000 to SP4, so I can upgrade it to 2008 later, but I'm getting this error. I tried with windows login that have administrator privileges, and with sa password as well, but result is the same.

Help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Which account was used to install SQL Server?

Comment: local "Administator" account, same one I'm trying with now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

**You may receive the "Setup was unable to validate the logged user" error message when you install SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 3**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814844

Method 1

Change the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo\DSQUERY
value to DBNETLIB.

- Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
- In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
- Double-click DSQUERY.
- In Value data box, type DBNETLIB, and then click OK.
- Exit Registry Editor.

Method 2

Make sure that the NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation registry key is set to 0. When this key is set to 0, you can access folders that have spaces in their names by using short names. To set the registry key, follow these steps:

- Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
- In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
- Double-click NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation.
- In the Value data box, type 0, and then click OK.
- Exit Registry Editor.

Make sure that the TEMP environment variable and the TMP environment variable do not contain spaces. To verify this, follow these steps:

- Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
- On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
- In the User Variables for logged-on user list, select TMP and then click Edit. Make sure that there are no spaces in the Variable Value text box, particularly any trailing spaces, and then click OK.
- Select TEMP, and then click Edit. Make sure that there are no spaces in the Variable Value text box, particularly any trailing spaces, and then click OK.
- If any of the variable values contain spaces, create a new temporary folder that does not contain spaces. For example, you can create the C:\Temp folder. Then, specify the new folder as the variable value for the TEMP environment variable and for the TMP environment variable.

Comment: Tried already, but results are the same.